# Ask about mysql select

Tags: mysql, select

```
select * from User where id>=0 and id<=10000
```

and

```
select * from User where id=0
select * from User where id=1
select * from User where id=2
...
select * from User where id=10000
```

Is there a huge difference about time or memory cost between these two ways?

Comment: Well, in the first case you make only 1 query, in the second you make thousands! Certainly there is...

Comment: What's the point of your question?  It should be obvious that typing 10k lines of code versus typing 1 line of code and asking which is better is rhetorical, so what is your underlying point?

Comment: It doesn't cost anything to make such optimization . You can check it by adding 'explain' in front of the query . Eg. Explain select * from User where id>=0 and id<=10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider batching the data load, instead of loading (almost) everything at once or one at a time, try loading them 10 or 100 records at a time, although you'd have to fire more than 1 query, the overall performance will improve ...
 like @steve-horvath recommended, please run some benchmarking to know for sure which is the best number of records to load at a time.

```
select * from User where id between 0 and 100
select * from User where id between 101 and 200
select * from User where id between 201 and 300
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the User table, but usually the memory footprint for 10k rows isn't too bad.

I recommend trying and benchmarking it out, if you're really keen.